# How to build linphone android sdk only for audio calls?

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am working on to build linphone-android-sdk only for audio calls, but did not got any link for the same. Can any body help me doing this.

I am currently using this command to disable video

```
./prepare.py -DENABLE-VIDEO=OFF
```

But I want to disable all the codecs and tools used in video and make the library usable only for audio.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the prepare.py script to disable the codecs. Refer to the section **if self.args.all_codecs:** in prepare.py. Also run './prepare.py -DENABLE-VIDEO=OFF --all-codecs' to take effect of the modified Codec defnitions

Comment: Hi @Lakshmi I tried this but the size of .aar file is not reducing , it's actually less when I only use -DENABLE_VIDEO=OFF with the ./prepare.py command. How to actually reduce size of the .aar file??

Comment: Try removing the submodules and externals in your repo which you are turning OFF in your script. If you include the submodules it may increase the size of aar

Comment: Hi @Laksmi can you give more details over this because if I remove the sbmodules it might give error in compilation. Can you please give some steps to do so?

Comment: Basically you need to remove submodules of Codecs which you are turning OFF and check if you see any difference in size of output. To remove submodule for e.g gsm, you turn off in your prepare.py script and use following commands to remove to try build 1. git submodule deinit -f -- <path-to-submodules>/externals/gsm 2. rm -rf .git/modules/<path-to-submodules>/externals/gsm 3. git rm -f <path-to-submodules>/externals/gsm